# Instagram oAuth2 unable to get the token

Tags: php, curl, instagram

I try to make a PHP script for Instagram.

First I request a "CODE" and then via the CODE I request a TOKEN. With the token I execute for an endpoint.

When I use this via the command line:

```
( https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/ )
    curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
    -F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
    -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
    -F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
    -F 'code=CODE' \
```

...it works perfect: I receive the TOKEN, but when I convert it to CURL/PHP it fails.

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://www..rightu.uri....&code=12345677
```

When I run it via my PHP script to get the token, I get an empty Instagram output page.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$clientid = 'xxxxx';
$clientsecret = 'yyyyy';
$redirecturi    = 'http://www.krnet.url/instaread';

if($_GET["code"]){
    $code=$_GET["code"];
    echo "code = $code<br>";
    getAccessToken($accessToken,$code,$clientid,$clientsecret,$redirecturi);
}else{
    echo "click for token";
}

function getAccessToken($accessToken,$code,$clientid,$clientsecret,$redirecturi) {
    $url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={$clientid}&client_secret={$clientsecret}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri={$redirecturi}&code={$code}";
    echo "<a href=$url>$url</>";
}

if (isset($zaccessToken)) {
    $url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token={$accessToken}";
    $headers = array("Content-type: application/json");

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $st=curl_exec($ch);
    foreach ($result['data'] as $item) {

    }
} else {
    $loginUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=1d50f5039bfc4d57aa845a978da25169&redirect_uri=http://www.kraan.net/instaread&response_type=code';
    echo '<center><a href="' . $loginUrl . '"><img src=instagram.png></a></center>';
}
```

Comment: How your php code looks like?